# Is it safe to buy a replacement laptop battery that has slightly different voltage than the original?

Tags: laptop, battery

I'm looking for a new battery for my Acer Aspire 4741g laptop. I am trying to get a higher capacity battery.

Many sites (like [this one](http://www.cheap-laptop-batteries.com/laptop-battery/acer-as10d41.htm) and [this one](http://www.adapterstore.org/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1_2&products_id=7587)) list batteries that are interchangeable with the battery that came with the laptop (AS10D41). These batteries have higher capacity, but also marginally lower voltage (11.1V vs. 11.8V). Is this a problem? Does it mean that the battery is actually incompatible? The replacement battery I am looking at is AS10G3E, and is listed in many places as being compatible with the AS10D41, but nobody makes any mention of the differing voltages.

I am trying to find out what kind of problems a lower voltage battery can cause. I know `P=IV`; with reduced voltage, will the machine draw more current, possibly damaging components? I'm just speculating, but I'm worried about the chance that using a battery at a lower voltage will damage my laptop.

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question so that it moves away from the "Buying recommendation"-Close-reason and more towards "How much does the battery-voltage matter"-section?

Comment: I have added a bit more to the question to better ask my question as to weather it will cause problems to use a lower voltage battery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power from the battery will have to be converted into a number of other voltages regardless of the voltage of the battery:

- +/- 12V
- +/- 5V
- +/- 3.3V

Plus others internally depending on hardware requirements (such as 1.75v for Vcore for some processors etc).

Even an +11.8v battery will have to be adjusted (through a DC-DC convertor) to +12v.

There should be no real difference in this.  Yes, the step-up to 12v will be slightly harder work, but then the step down to 5v and 3.3v will be less work, so it should all even out.

Comment: Seems a valid answer